# How to get the key and values of a list of objects where I created from a class. Python

Tags: list, function, class, object, default

```
class BallPlayer:
    def __init__(self,name:str,number:int,goals:int,assists:int,minutes:int):
        self.minutes = minutes
        self.assists = assists
        self.goals = goals
        self.number = number
        self.name = name
        


def most_goals(a:list):
    newList=sorted(a, key=lambda item:item.goals,reverse=True)
    return newList
```

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    player1 = BallPlayer("Archie Bonkers", 13, 5, 12, 46)
    player2 = BallPlayer("Speedy Tickets", 7, 2, 26, 55)
    player3 = BallPlayer("Cruella De Hill", 9, 1, 32, 26)
    player4 = BallPlayer("Devilled Tasmanian", 12, 1, 11, 41)
    player5 = BallPlayer("Donald Quack", 4, 3, 9, 12)
    
    team = [player1, player2, player3, player4, player5]
    print(most_goals(team))
```

I create a class and create objects from that class and put them in a list. A function takes the list and should return me the name of the most scorer player. I cannot get any value by using newList[0].name and the newList gives me a list of codes that i do not understand as

[<**main**.BallPlayer object at 0x000001D6FA4833C8>, <**main**.BallPlayer object at 0x000001D6FA487288>, <**main**.BallPlayer object at 0x000001D6FA4871C8>, <**main**.BallPlayer object at 0x000001D6FA487208>, <**main**.BallPlayer object at 0x000001D6FA487248>]

What should I do to get the values from this list of objects like a normal list?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to get the name of the player with the most goals:

```
def most_goals(a:list):
    newList=sorted(a, key=(lambda item:item.goals))
    return newList[0].name
```

This will sort the list of objects by the `goals` attribute, accessing it with a lambda function for each item. Instead of returning the entire list of objects, it will now return the first object's `name` attribute.